# Not getting result : working with completableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, completable-future

I suppose to get the response from two API and then only move forward. To achieve this tried to use completableFuture but ending up in getting NullPointerException, when fetching response from 'result' object.
Infact, completeableFuture basically not have data.
Not able to debug the thread working directly.

```
public APIResult execute() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        CompletableFuture<TaskChair> completableFutureChair = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->new TaskChair(),executorChair);
        CompletableFuture<TaskBottle> completableFutureBottle = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->new TaskBottle(),executorChair);


        CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureChair, completableFutureBottle);
        combinedFuture.get();

        TaskChair taskChair = completableFutureChair.get();
        TaskBottle taskBottle = completableFutureBottle.get();

        List<Chair> chairs = taskChair.getChairs();
        List<Bottle> bottles = taskBottle.getBottles();

        APIResult result = new APIResult(chairs, bottles);

        return result;
    }


class TaskChair implements Callable<List<Chair>>{

    List<Chair> chairs;

    public List<Chair> getChairs() {
        return chairs;
    }
    public void setChairs(List<Chair> chairs) {
        this.chairs = chairs;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Chair> call() throws Exception {
        chairs = new RestAPI().getChairs();
        return chairs;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestService service = new RestService();
        APIResult result = null;

        try {
            result = service.execute();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) { }

        System.out.println("Chair API Status -> ");
        for(Chair chair:result.getChairs()) {
            System.out.println(" id : "+chair.getId()+" name : "+ chair.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please can you supply the stacktrace?  Where do you set `executorChair` and `completableFutureCabin`?

Comment: `null` is the initial value of `TaskChair.chairs` and since no-one is ever invoking the `TaskChair.call()` method, the variable will stay `null`. There is no point in doing `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->new TaskChair(),executorChair)`, as `new TaskChair()` is executing the compiler generated default constructor which will simply do nothing (besides invoking `super()`, which also does nothing). So you’re performing a no-op asynchronously.

Comment: @John, I have created like this- ExecutorService executorChair = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);